# Why Docx4j is not removing Content Controls from docx files?

Tags: java, xml, docx, docx4j

I am trying to merge XML and docx using DOcx4J. But even if I use the flag Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT Docx4J is not removing the Content controls from the docx file. I am using the below code.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(docx_template_location));
FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(xml_data_location));
Docx4J.bind(wordprocessingMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML & Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
Docx4J.save(wordprocessingMLPackage, new File(required_outputfile_name), Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_ZIP_FILE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this commit](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/b9e3ff76ac70af65b56d17a60d7fe211bbc9471c)

Prior to that (on 3.3 branch), it removed only OpenDoPE content controls

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to remove content controls form a MS Word docx using Docx4J, if not when can we expect that feature? (As you are the creator of that library)

Comment: You can use a 3.3 nightly build, backport the code to 3.2.x (simple enough), or just make copies of the 2 files (the java code and xslt) suitably renamed in your own code.

Comment: I used 3.3; now DOcx4J is not merging XML with docx template. I do not get a output docx with the merged data. I get a pdf but that is of size 0KB.

Comment: 3.3 current GitHub source seems fine to me; if you continue to have problems, you should create another question here or in the docx4j forums.  You'll need to include your code and your inputs.

Comment: By the way, here is the current 3.3.0 distribution; please read the changelog file!  http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-community-3.3.0-nightly-20160120.zip

Comment: The Docx4J 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT works perfectly well. But there is a pdf conversio error. I see the Docx4J is using it's own pdf converter and the error is posted in a different thread here in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898260/how-to-solve-the-docx-to-pdf-conversion-error-when-using-docx4j-3-3-0-snapshot

Comment: Answered that question